# How to recover data from synology Raid 5?

Tags: data-recovery, nas, raid5, synology

My old synology server (cs407s), died. So I'm trying to retrieve the data from the disk. I have tree disks from RAID 5. I tried to mount the disk on computer running grml.

```
# lsblk
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 768.7M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0 384.4M  0 part
└─sda3   8:3    0 464.5G  0 part
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0 768.7M  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0 384.4M  0 part
└─sdb3   8:19   0 464.5G  0 part
sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0 768.7M  0 part
├─sdc2   8:34   0 384.4M  0 part
└─sdc3   8:35   0 464.5G  0 part
```

and

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan -v                                                                                :(
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdc3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdc2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

**Output of informational commands:**
“to see which devices have no obvious metadata”

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sd*  > /dev/null
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda1.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda2.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda3.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb1.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb2.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb3.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc1.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc2.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc3.
```

“to see what information we do have”

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sd* 2> /dev/null
/dev/sda: MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] : 1574307 sectors at 63 (type fd)
Partition[1] : 787185 sectors at 1574370 (type fd)
Partition[2] : 974133405 sectors at 2634660 (type fd)
/dev/sdb: MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] : 1574307 sectors at 63 (type fd)
Partition[1] : 787185 sectors at 1574370 (type fd)
Partition[2] : 974133405 sectors at 2634660 (type fd)
/dev/sdc: MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] : 1574307 sectors at 63 (type fd)
Partition[1] : 787185 sectors at 1574370 (type fd)
Partition[2] : 974133405 sectors at 2634660 (type fd)
```

```
# pvscan
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  No matching physical volumes found`
```

Any suggestion about how to proceed from here?

Note: I installed this more than 8 years ago, using via the dsm sofware. So, I've probably used the default. I don't know whether that's is shr or traditional raid.

Comment: Is this [SHR](https://nascompares.com/2016/07/06/what-is-shr-and-what-is-the-difference-between-synology-hybrid-raid-and-ordinary-raid/) (the default for a Synology device) or "traditional" RAID5?

Comment: good question. I install this more than 8 years ago, using via the dsm sofware. So, i'be proberbly used the default. I don't know whether that's is shr or traditional raid

Comment: OK. First of all. Don't use `--assemble` or `--run` or `--create` under any circumstances until you completely understand the command. Any of these could destroy your remaining data if used wrongly.

Comment: see edit of question

Comment: Is the data just lost? Would it be an idea to buy a new synology NAS and reuse the disc in hope they are automatically detected by synology DSM

Comment: Just seen your update - sorry I missed it earlier. If neither `mdadm` nor `pvscan` can find anything exciting I don't think I will be able to help you any further, unfortunately. Good luck.